Why are network file transfers extremely slow or completely freeze when Home Assistant is running?
I am running Home Assistant and some home-made utilities on my Raspberry PI 3, and occasionally need to transfer files to it over wi-fi, either downloading from the Pi with wget or similar, or uploading from a computer on the same network with scp.
For some reason, transfers are extremely slow, when they work at all, unless I kill Home Assistant, in which case it is very fast. What could be the reason for that? (and more importantly, how can I investigate the issue?)
Here's the first lines of top on the Pi during a stalled file transfer:
top - 15:52:58 up  2:58,  1 user,  load average: 0.13, 0.17, 0.17
Tasks: 133 total,   1 running, 132 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.1 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.7 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st 
MiB Mem :    908.6 total,     85.1 free,    410.7 used,    476.3 buff/cache     
MiB Swap:    200.0 total,    198.2 free,      1.8 used.    497.9 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                        
    465 root      20   0  404016   1664   1404 S   6.6   0.2  11:32.02 pigpiod                                                                                                        
   3603 homeass+  20   0 1535960 233244  50960 S   3.0  25.1   0:31.99 hass                                                                                                           
    514 root      20   0  262232  16688  13552 S   2.6   1.8   4:15.05 NetworkManager                                                                                                 
    447 message+  20   0    8796   3968   3088 S   2.3   0.4   3:35.88 dbus-daemon                                                                                                    
    606 root      20   0   13304   5212   4496 S   1.3   0.6   2:22.89 bluetoothd                                                                                                     
   3626 pi        20   0   11736   4996   2836 R   1.0   0.5   0:02.91 top                                                                                                            
    409 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:12.16 kworker/u9:2-brcmf_wq/mmc1:0001:1                                                                              
    480 root      20   0 9346452 118148  38588 S   0.3  12.7   1:20.72 node                                                                                                           
   3516 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.24 kworker/1:1-events                                                                                             
      1 root      20   0  168644  11964   8508 S   0.0   1.3   0:05.03 systemd                                                                                                        
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.05 kthreadd                                                                                                       
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                         
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                       

(Note that I'm running that top through an SSH connection and it keeps updating, so network still works well enough for that)
Meanwhile, client-side, the scp command shows this, i.e. it was able to send 255 kb and then stalled there.
myfile                             0%  255KB   0.0KB/s - stalled -
I got into the habit of killing Home Assistant whenever I need to transfer something and then starting it again, but it means people can't turn lights on or off when I'm transferring file, which isn't ideal :)
Other devices on the network work fine.
ping works fine:
PING raspberry (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=164 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=18.7 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=17.7 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=17.4 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=17.4 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=16.9 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=16.4 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=17.7 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=29.1 ms
64 bytes from raspberry (10.0.0.2): icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=18.0 ms
^C
--- raspberry ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 14 received, 0% packet loss, time 13017ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.056/28.838/164.260/37.695 ms

I ran tcpdump on the Raspberry while trying to send it a file over SSH and it shows a lot of "TCP Dup ACK" sent from the Raspberry to my laptop. From what I understand it means the Raspberry is not receiving expected packets from my laptop?

